# MakeGood + PHPUnit + Eclipse Luna

Tags: php, eclipse, phpunit, makegood

I try to do tests with PHPUnit & MakeGood on Eclipse but when i run the test from MakeGood i have an error like that :

"Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite' not found in D:\Downloads\eclipse\plugins\com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehandtestrunner_3.1.1.v201409021510\resources\php\vendor\piece\stagehand-testrunner\src\Collector\PHPUnitCollector.php on line 124

Call Stack:
    0.0029     267904   1. {main}() 
D:\Downloads\eclipse\plugins\com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehandtestrunner_3.1.1.v201409021510\resources\php\bin\testrunner.php:0

```
0.3527    2733800   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() D:\Downloads\eclipse\plugins\com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehandtestrunner_3.1.1.v201409021510\resources\php\bin\testrunner.php:55
0.3988    3124008   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() D:\Downloads\eclipse\plugins\com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehandtestrunner_3.1.1.v201409021510\resources\php\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:124
0.4046    3125048   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() D:\Downloads\eclipse\plugins\com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehandtestrunner_3.1.1.v201409021510\resources\php\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:193
0.4052    3125472   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() D:\Downloads\eclipse\plugins\com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehandtestrunner_3.1.1.v201409021510\resources\php\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Application.php:887
0.4398    3131080   6. Stagehand\TestRunner\CLI\TestRunnerApplication\Command\PluginCommand->execute() D:\Downloads\eclipse\plugins\com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehandtestrunner_3.1.1.v201409021510\resources\php\vendor\symfony\console\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command.php:252
0.6717    4411720   7. Stagehand\TestRunner\CLI\TestRunnerApplication\Command\PluginCommand->createTestRunner() D:\Downloads\eclipse\plugins\com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehandtestrunner_3.1.1.v201409021510\resources\php\vendor\piece\stagehand-testrunner\src\CLI\TestRunnerApplication\Command\PluginCommand.php:149
0.6718    4411848   8. Stagehand\TestRunner\Core\ApplicationContext->createComponent() D:\Downloads\eclipse\plugins\com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehandtestrunner_3.1.1.v201409021510\resources\php\vendor\piece\stagehand-testrunner\src\CLI\TestRunnerApplication\Command\PluginCommand.php:295
0.6718    4411912   9. Stagehand\ComponentFactory\ComponentFactory->create() D:\Downloads\eclipse\plugins\com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehandtestrunner_3.1.1.v201409021510\resources\php\vendor\piece\stagehand-testrunner\src\Core\ApplicationContext.php:104
0.6720    4412416  10. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() D:\Downloads\eclipse\plugins\com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehandtestrunner_3.1.1.v201409021510\resources\php\vendor\piece\stagehand-componentfactory\src\Stagehand\ComponentFactory\ComponentFactory.php:76
0.6721    4413008  11. Stagehand\TestRunner\DependencyInjection\PHPUnitContainer->getTestRunnerService() D:\Downloads\eclipse\plugins\com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehandtestrunner_3.1.1.v201409021510\resources\php\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container.php:312
0.6854    4475880  12. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() D:\Downloads\eclipse\plugins\com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehandtestrunner_3.1.1.v201409021510\resources\php\vendor\piece\stagehand-testrunner\src\DependencyInjection\PHPUnitContainer.php:448
0.6856    4476408  13. Stagehand\TestRunner\DependencyInjection\PHPUnitContainer->getPhpunit_CollectorService() D:\Downloads\eclipse\plugins\com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehandtestrunner_3.1.1.v201409021510\resources\php\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container.php:312
0.6943    4601016  14. Stagehand\TestRunner\Collector\Collector->__construct() D:\Downloads\eclipse\plugins\com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehandtestrunner_3.1.1.v201409021510\resources\php\vendor\piece\stagehand-testrunner\src\DependencyInjection\PHPUnitContainer.php:302
0.6943    4601120  15. Stagehand\TestRunner\Collector\PHPUnitCollector->createTestSuite() D:\Downloads\eclipse\plugins\com.piece_framework.makegood.stagehandtestrunner_3.1.1.v201409021510\resources\php\vendor\piece\stagehand-testrunner\src\Collector\Collector.php:92
```

"

I correctly import the phpunit.phar in my project on Eclipse (because after this december Pear will be no longer available with PHPUnit) but MakeGood look as he doesn't really happy ...

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, MakeGood does not support phpunit.phar. Use PHPUnit as a Composer package as the following:

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit "4.4.*"
```